# win32_physicalMemory.Capacity returns null in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

This is a really weird issue that only occurs on one computer that I've tested on.

I have the following line of code:

```
(get-WmiObject win32_physicalMemory -Impersonation 3 -ComputerName "localhost").Capacity
```

which returns null for some reason. However, on the same computer, if I run the command:

```
get-WmiObject win32_physicalMemory -Impersonation 3 -ComputerName "localhost"
```

I get the info for two sticks of ram, each of which have a capacity of 8589934592 (8GB). The computer is on Powershell version 2, and this same operation on other computers (with Powershell versions between 2 and 4) would return, instead of null, the capacity from each stick of ram.

Why am I getting different results from the same commands, even when the Powershell version remains the same across computers?

Comment: What OS do you have on that PC with 2x8GB modules? And, what version of Powershell do you use, x86 or x64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because with powershell 2.0 you can't access an array with that method.

```
get-WmiObject win32_physicalMemory -Impersonation 3 -ComputerName "localhost" | select -expand capacity
```

that will work

the other powershell 2.0 computers you mention probably only have one stick of memory, so it doesn't return an array

Comment: And I was wondering why my PS4.0 over Win7 returns proper value set with that method. One quickly accommodates to whatever is good.

Comment: Awesome, that's totally it! Thanks so much!